# Showing a complex function defined as an integral is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ be any $C^1$ curve. Define $$f(z)=\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{\zeta-z}d\zeta.$$
>   Prove that $f$ is holomorphic on $U=\mathbb{C}-\hat{\gamma}$ where $\hat{\gamma}=\{ \gamma(t):0\leq t\leq 1 \} .$ In case $\gamma(t)=t,$ show that there is no way to extend $f$ to a continuous function on all of $\mathbb{C}$.

I know in my head we're really discussing the complex logarithm here, and in the second part in specific we are discussing, say, $Log(\frac{z}{z-1})$ which has $[0,1]$ as its branch cut (not sure if I am using the terminology correctly here). My initial thoughts on the first part are to somehow use Morera's Theorem or simply to use the definition of differentiation, but I can't sort out how the details would work.

Comment: The integral notation indicates the curve is closed, although you allow the curve to be arbitrary. So which is it?

Comment: Cass, I noticed this as well. The question is ported directly as seen in Greene and Kranz, Function Theory of One Complex Variable, 3rd edition, page 94. I am assuming an arbitrary curve because the second part indicates a curve that is not closed.

Comment: Proving that $f$ is holomorphic boils down to the fact that since you are integrating with respect to $\zeta$ not $z$, you can pull $z$ limits inside the integral. Hence, you can pull partial with respect to $x$, partial with respect to $y$, and therefore partial with respect to $\bar{z}$ inside the integral.

Comment: For the second part, go by contradiction. Suppose $f$ extends. Then consider the closed curve $g(t)=e^{2\pi it}$. Then, $f(g(t))$ is also continuous and is in fact equal to $2 \pi i t$, off the real axis at least. On the other hand, you should have the values at $t=0$ and $t=1$ being equal. But this clearly cannot be the case if $f(g(t))$ is continuous.

Comment: Edit: The $2 \pi it$ may not be quite correct, but the same argument works.

Comment: Cass, I just found a proof (Lang 1999 pp. 130-131). He proves $f$ is holomorphic by building a power series out of it around any selected point in $U$. Clever! 

He also suggests something like what you have suggested - namely, to differentiate by z and obtain the usual integral formula for derivatives. I had a temptation to do this, but the justification for differentiating under the integral sign is not clear to me.

Comment: I learned complex analysis from Greene and Krantz a couple of years ago. At some point, they certainly (with justification) pull limits and derivatives into the integral, so if you flip around the book, you may find it.

Comment: Cass, I'm trying to understand your answer to the second part, but I cannot seem to see what you're seeing. Parameterizing, we would get $\int_0^1 \frac{2 \pi i e^{2 \pi i t}}{t-e^{2 \pi i t}}dt$ correct? Wouldn't that have an issue at $t=1$?

Comment: The comment was just my gut feeling of how the answer should work. It works similarly, involving looking at opposite sides of x=1 on the unit circle, but for a precise result, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the question, if $\gamma(t)=t$ and $z=x+iy$ is not on the positive real axis, then

$f(z)=\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{\zeta-z}d\zeta=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(t-x)-iy}dt=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(t-x)+iy}{(t-x)^2+y^2}dt$

$=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(t-x)}{(t-x)^2+y^2}dt + iy\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(t-x)^2+y^2}dt$

$=(1/2)\int\frac{ds}{s}ds + (i/y)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{[(t-x)/y]^2+1}dt$ for $s=(t-x)^2+y^2$.

$=(1/2)ln|s|+iarctan((t-x)/y)$ evaluated over the interval $[0,1]$.

Back substituting the expression for $s$, one sees that the final number is

$f(z)=(1/2)ln|1-2x+r^2|-ln|r|+i[arctan((1-x)/y)+arctan(x/y)]$,

where $r^2$ as usual is $x^2 + y^2$.

Now suppose $f$ extends. Taking $z=cos\tau+isin\tau$, which is a parameterization of the unit circle, we have for $\tau \neq n\pi$,

$f(z(\tau))=(1/2)ln|2-2cos\tau|+i[arctan((1-cos\tau)/sin\tau)+arctan(cot\tau)]$,

Now since we believe that $f$ is continuous over all of $\mathbb{C}$, the functions corresponding to its real and imaginary parts also extend continuously over $\mathbb{C}$. In particular, the function

$g(\tau):=Im(f(z(\tau)))= arctan((1-cos\tau)/sin\tau)+arctan(cot\tau)$,

where this equality holds for $\tau \neq n\pi$ extends to a continuous function of $\tau$. But this cannot be since the limit of $g$ as $\tau$ approaches 0 from the left is $arctan(-\infty)+arctan(-\infty)=-\pi$. On the other hand, the limit as $\tau$ approaches 0 from the right is $arctan(\infty)+arctan(\infty)=\pi$, so there's no hope of finding a value of $g$ at $\tau=0$ (hence, of $f$ at $z=1$) that makes this function continuous.

Note that the imaginary parts differ on opposite sides of $\gamma$ by $2\pi$. This is as expected.

Comment: I also had a thought of somehow forcing the result to be $Log (\frac{z}{z-1})$ which we would define a cut on $[0,1]$ and then proceed to argue that continuation is impossible as the imaginary parts would differ by $2 \pi$ across the cut (as you indicated in your calculation). I do not know whether my particular presentation is valid.